# Can I apply a :hover pseudo selector with the LESS css markup?

Tags: html, css, less

In LESS I can apply two rules like this to affect text styling of links to hide underline unless hovered:

```
.read-more
{
    a
    {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    a:hover
    {
        text-decoration:hover;
    }
}
```

But I feel like I should also be able to define two rules like this:

```
.reverseHover
{
    text-decoration:none;
}

.reverseHover:hover
{
    text-decoration:hover;
}
```

And then use a `mixin` to get both rules:

```
.read-more{
    a
    {
        .reverseHover;
    }
}
```

Without having to explicitly do something like this:

```
.read-more{
    a{
        .reverseHover;
    }
    a.reverseHover:hover
    {
        .reverseHover;
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can reference the parent selector using `&`.  You can even use a parent selector in a mixin.  Documentation is found at [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature).  Below is the solution.

```
.reverseHover {
    text-decoration:none;
    &:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
}
.read-more
{
    a
    {
        .reverseHover
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know of any "hidden" ones.  But if you want a reference go to http://lesscss.org/ and use the language dropdown menu for more documentation.